# A force is not parallel to the velocity of body but makes some angle with it. What does it do

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Does velocity acts always in the direction of motion? In what cases direction of force and velocity are different? What happens if force is not parallel to the velocity of body and makes some angle with it what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

> Does velocity acts always in the direction of motion?

I don't understand this question, but velocity describes the motion. A correct statement would be the changes in the velocity are always parallel to the force.

> In what cases direction of force and velocity are different?

If you had a component of velocity in $y$-direction $v_y\hat{j}$, then a force acting in the $x$-direction $F_x\hat{i}$ doesn't do anything to $v_y$ it only changes $v_x$.

> What happens if force is not parallel to the velocity of the body and makes some angle with it what does it do?

When force in not parallel to the velocity, you divide the force into two components, parallel and perpendicular. You can always rotate your coordinate system such that the velocity is in the $x$-direction.
$$\vec{v} = v_x\hat{i}$$
where $v_x$ is the $x$ component of the velocity.
If force $F$ makes angle $\theta$ with the velocty $v$ then we can write $$\vec{F} = |F|\cdot (\cos(\theta)\hat{i} + \sin(\theta)\hat{j})$$
where $F_x = |F|\cdot \cos(\theta)$ which is the parallel component, to the velocity, of the force and $F_y = |F|\cdot \sin(\theta)$ is the perpendicular component of the force. You can now break your problem in two. 1) velocity and force in the $x$-direction. 2) velocity and force in the $y$-direction.

Answer (score 1):

SamD97 provides a definitive answer. In case the OP doesn't understand fully the advanced notation, here's an attempt at a simplification:

Velocity doesn't *act*. Rather a velocity is what you end up with after a *force* has acted. So a rowing boat, sitting on a still lake has no velocity. The rower dips his oars into the water a gives a stroke. This applies a force to the boat in the forward direction. It accelerates during the stroke and, when he finishes, the boat now has a velocity along the direction the boat is pointing.

Now the boat enters a current that is flowing across the direction of motion at right-angles. This accelerates it until it now has an additional velocity to the side. The boat still points in the direction it was originally heading but is now also slipping sideways. Seen from above, the boat is moving diagonally. What has happened is that the two velocities add together as *vectors*; they form two sides of a triangle and the resultant motion is the third side.